# React to changes in model when usercontrol updates it

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have created a custom control that updates my model thanks to two way binding, using mvvm light.

```
<cbtn:BillCounter Value="{Binding MoneyTypes[0].Paid, Mode=TwoWay }" />
```

MoneyTypes is an array that contains several of them. I see that when i check that array that my changes have gone thru to the array in the model, values are updated. However, i would need to recalculate other values based on the changes that are happening, when they happen. Is there any way that my model can be notified that changes have happened to it with the kind of binding i'm using above?

This is a continuation of this question: [Binding to an array of structs in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171096/binding-to-an-array-of-structs-in-wpf), but now i need to make the model react to the changes the custom control does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `MoneyType` classes are implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can listen to the change events in the `ViewModel` and simply notify the `Model` when they occur:

Here's a `ViewModel` that will subscribe to all `MoneyType` changes. Whenever a change occurs, simply call the method on the `Model` to re-calculate

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    private IMyModel _myModel;

    public MyViewModel(MyModel myModel)
    {
        _myModel = myModel;

        foreach (var moneyType in MoneyType)
        {
            moneyType.OnPropertyChanged += MoneyTypePropetyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnMoneyTypePropetyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _myModel.NotifyMoneyTypeChanged();   
    }
}
```

Expose the needed method in the Model

```
public class MyModel : IMyModel
{
    public void NotifyMoneyTypeChanged()   
    {
       // do work here
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically the custom control in the  `view` is causing changes in the `model`, which are then picked up in the `viewmodel`, which then calls a function in the `model` to  trigger the update calculation?

Comment: You should be bound to the ViewModel (which exposes the Model to the View). The ViewModel will then get all the notifications of the change and from here you can notify the Model. How does your Model look like?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever properties are updated by tertiary properties, the model just needs to call PropertyChanged.  So, for each property, they first would update their property `PropertyChanged("PropertyName")` and then they would update the other properties that rely on this property `PropertyChanged("SomeOtherProperty");`  Basically, you just have to call a series of property changed events to bubble it back up to the UI to see the new calculations.