# Edited cell content in dataGridView with data binding will not be stored

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

In order to experiment with data binding I have created a simple dataGridview with two rows and two columns.
The initial cell contents are being diplayed correctly.
When (for example) I try to edit the content in row 2 of column "ID" from 2 to 5 the value flips back to 2 when pressing enter.
Setting a breakpoint in the write method of the ID-Property shows that the new value is written to _id.
But it seems that it does not to arrive in "data"-Array.
That's my code:

```
public struct Record
{
    public int _id;
    public int ID
    { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
} 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Record[] data;
    public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        data = new Record[2] ;
        data[0].ID = 1;
        data[0].Name = "Alf";
        data[1].ID = 2;
        data[1].Name = "Bert";

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].DataPropertyName = "ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns["Customer"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

        bs.DataSource = typeof(Record);
        bs.Add(data[0]);
        bs.Add(data[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to use a struct instead of a class?

Comment: do a quick google search on how to store data inside of a `DataView` and assign that value to bind to the Datagridview else use the original datatable when binding.. very simple

Comment: If you use a class instead of a struct you will not experience the problem

Comment: Of course then you need to data[0] = new Record() before using that element

Comment: @Steve: Changing the struct to class did solve the problem, Thank You! But do be honest: I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714883/why-does-binding-to-a-struct-not-work